# How to escape strings in pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to know how to escape strings in pdo .
I have been escaping the springs like in the code bellow but now with pdo I do not know how to do it

```
$username=(isset($_POST['username']))? trim($_POST['username']): '';
$previlage =(isset($_GET['previlage']));
$query ="SELECT * FROM site_user 
WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' AND  previlage ='Admin'";
$security = mysql_query($query)or die (mysql_error($con));
$count = mysql_num_rows($security);
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` for session values?

Comment: Do not use depricated mysql_* functions. use PDO/MySQLi instead.

Comment: @Mr.Alien — Presumably because the session contains text and not pre-escaped fragments of SQL. You should always escape text before inserting it into a data format or a string that will be evaluated as code.

Comment: @Boynux — The question is asking *how* to do that!

Comment: @Quentin I guess he must be using a regex to remove non username characters like `$#@%^!` etc, and am sure he fetches the data from the database and assigning it to username session

Comment: @Boynux am not using it iam asking a question on PDO this means I shifted to pdo

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, you can use [**PDO::quote**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), but, as said in its own docpage...

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use [**PDO::prepare()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement.

In your case it can look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM site_user 
           WHERE username = :username AND previlage = 'Admin'";
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username']) );
```

Comment: great u provided what I asked thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_*` function will not work in PDO. WHY? Because PDO doesnt use mysql to connect to a databases, as far as input sanitization, PDO uses prepared statements you can find a good tutorial for that here: [pdo](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)