# Unable to quote table name in PDO with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, quoting

I have to work with somebody's database for a game which sadly has a table named "User" or [dbo][User] and this can not be renamed.
Now, I need to access this using PDO in PHP and when I use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT UserId AS INTUSERID FROM dbo.User WHERE YahooId = 'abcdef'";
```

it fails, as in nothing is fetched since "User" is a reserved keyword there. From the MS SQL Server I can do this as:

```
SELECT UserId AS INTUSERID FROM [GameName].[dbo].[User] WHERE YahooId = 'abcdef'
```

and it works.
How should I prepare my query in PHP to make this execute? I have tried to put single quotes around table name but that has no effect.
What is the correct way to use

```
[GameName].[dbo].[User]
```

from PHP PDO as the table name ?

**Update:**
This is how I am connecting:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("xxx.rds.amazonaws.com,1150;Database=xyz","admin","password");
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: I think this is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091734/how-to-escape-strings-in-pdo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo

Comment: I have tried PDO prepare but those threads seem to be for parameters. In my case, the table name itself is a reserved keyword...

Comment: @MrVimes Tried backticks... does not have effect. I echoed the query and shows with backticks but does not execute.

Comment: I deleted my comment as I didn't realize you were using mssql not mysql.  Don't the square brackets work?

Comment: i.e. $query = "SELECT UserId AS INTUSERID FROM dbo.[User] WHERE YahooId = 'abcdef'";   I'd test myself but I'm on an ipad :)

Comment: what is your database name ?

Comment: The database name is maison and on other tables am able to use dbo.tableName since they are not keywords... 
@MrVimes square brackets work from SQL Server but not from PHP... :(

Comment: @NikhilKhullar you are not getting Connection failed msg ? and you are connecting to xxx.rds.amazonaws.com ?

Comment: Strange.  I'll check back on this question when I get to work.  I connect to mssql db with PDO there, and I'm curious about this.  Maybe you need to escape the brackets like this \\] but that's just a guess.

Comment: @MrVimes I will wait... and try \] now... Please check on a table named User
Thanks !

Comment: @MrVimes Escaping with backslashes '\[' and '\]' did not work... :(

Comment: @MrVimes Thanks for your help... It worked !
For some reason, just for this table I had to give db name too... It worked as this: "FROM [dbName].[dbo].[user]" ... Phew !

Comment: @MrVimes Post that as an answer to resolve the question.

Comment: Glad it worked :)   Wasn't sure whether to answer as my last suggestion was to escape the brackets with a slash.  But others finding this question would benefit from seeing an answer so I did.  Also, I did get a chance to try on my own code.  I didn't need to insert square brackets around the db name or db owner name,  just the table name,  and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the discussion in the comments I am providing this so that the question has an answer.  I thought square brackets would work fine within the php string used to define the query so I tested it out on my own code that connects to MS-SQL using PDO.

So the following should work...

`$query = "SELECT UserId AS INTUSERID FROM dbo.[User] WHERE YahooId = 'abcdef'";`

**Side note** - If your YahooId ever comes from a source that can be manipulated by a user (such as $_GET) you should research [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) with PDO...

```
$query = "SELECT UserId AS INTUSERID FROM dbo.[User] WHERE YahooId = ?;";

$statement= $db->prepare($query);

$statement->execute(array($userinput));
```

Comment: Thanks MrVimes. However for my case, I somehow have to use [dbName].[dbo].[User] ... It just doesn't work for this only without [dbName] . If you can guess the reason, please let me know. Other queries work fine. Anyways, after a few wonderful hours of debugging, the fight is over... :)
That yahooId comes from a session, so I guess, no security holes. I am using prepared statements for some other functions where parameters are complex, but to be honest this one wasn't working even when I was giving table name as a bindParam...