# Query using column named "index" using PDO and MSSQL database always returns nothing

Tags: php, sql-server, database, pdo

I have a database with 2 tables called `data.MonthlyNormalData` and `dev.Station` in which I want to use a query with an `INNER JOIN`. In that query, specifically in the `WHERE` clauses, I use a condition on a column named `index` from the `data.MonthlyNormalData` table. Of course, in sql server, `index` is a reserved word and I can escape it by writing the following: `WHERE [index] = 'foo'`.

Now my issue is that when doing my query in my PHP script using PDO, I don't receive any data, but in sql server, with the same query, I do see data returning from the query. I think that that is because in sql server I escaped the `index` keyword whereas in my script I did not. Is this really what is going on? If so, how can I resolve this problem?

For reference, here is the query in my PHP script:

```
$db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT MND.value, MND.normal_code FROM data.MonthlyNormalData AS MND INNER JOIN dev.Station AS S ON MND.station_id = S.station_id WHERE MND.element_id = $indice[1][0] AND MND.index = $indice[1][1] AND MND.threshold = $indice[1][2] AND MND.month = $monthNum AND S.station_id = $slt_idStations ORDER BY MND.last_updated DESC");
$stmt->execute();
if ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    array_push($queryResults, $row['value']);
}
else
{
    echo "NO DATA :'( !!!!! </br>";
}
```

Where $indices[1][x], $monthNum and $slt_idStations are integers. I have checked by `echo`'ing them that they have the right values, and they indeed do. The `ConnectionFactory` class sets up all the connection configuration and options for the PDO connection and I used it all throughout my code without any problems.

Here is the query I used on sql server and it worked (I replaced the PHP variables in the query by their actual values):

```
SELECT MND.value, MND.normal_code 
FROM [criacc_bd].[data].[MonthlyNormalData] AS MND 
INNER JOIN [criacc_bd].[dev].[Station] AS S 
ON MND.station_id = S.station_id 
WHERE MND.element_id = '54' 
AND MND.[index] = '0' 
AND MND.threshold = '0' 
AND MND.month = '12' 
AND S.station_id = '6047' 
ORDER BY MND.last_updated DESC
```

EDIT: Just got confirmation that the `index` column is the issue, as when I remove the `AND MND.index = $indice[1][1]` part of my PHP query, it does return values.

Comment: Why are you preparing a statement when you are injecting your variables directly in the query? You should bind your variables instead to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a mix of the `index` column and what Sammitch mentioned in his answer. The fix was to take Sammitch's answer and also escape the `index` with `[]` in the `prepare()` function like follows:

```
SELECT MND.value, MND.normal_code 
FROM data.MonthlyNormalData AS MND 
INNER JOIN dev.Station AS S 
ON MND.station_id = S.station_id 
WHERE MND.element_id = {$indice[1][0]} 
AND MND.[index] = {$indice[1][1]} 
AND MND.threshold = {$indice[1][2]} 
AND MND.month = $monthNum 
AND S.station_id = $slt_idStations 
ORDER BY MND.last_updated DESC
```

I found out about the bracket escaping by reading the following answer: [Unable to quote table name in PDO with MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348209/unable-to-quote-table-name-in-pdo-with-mssql?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your formatted query:

```
SELECT MND.value, MND.normal_code
FROM data.MonthlyNormalData AS MND INNER JOIN dev.Station AS S
  ON MND.station_id = S.station_id
WHERE
  MND.element_id = $indice[1][0] AND
  MND.index = $indice[1][1] AND
  MND.threshold = $indice[1][2] AND
  MND.month = $monthNum AND
  S.station_id = $slt_idStations
ORDER BY MND.last_updated DESC
```

You cannot expand array values inside of a quoted string like that, it needs to be:

```
SELECT MND.value, MND.normal_code
FROM data.MonthlyNormalData AS MND INNER JOIN dev.Station AS S
  ON MND.station_id = S.station_id
WHERE
  MND.element_id = {$indice[1][0]} AND
  MND.index = {$indice[1][1]} AND
  MND.threshold = {$indice[1][2]} AND
  MND.month = $monthNum AND
  S.station_id = $slt_idStations
ORDER BY MND.last_updated DESC
```

Or better yet, use parameters since you're clearly already using an engine that supports prepared statements.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it unfortunately is not the solution. The problem really lies with the index column, as when I remove the `AND MND.index = $indice[1][1]` part of my query in my PHP script, the query works perfectly (but doesn't return the exact data I want as there is a part missing in the query now). I will update my original question with that info.